# How do I create open ended questions with subjective answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, closing-questions, asking-questions

I wanted to ask an open ended question whose answer will be entirely subjective.  But I think the question and answer would be beneficial to the site.  This is technically something that should be flagged to be closed.

> "What are mapping or diagramming techniques that would be valuable to
>   someone mapping a solar system?"
>
> Basically, it's a question about creating maps or diagrams.  I've seen
>   number of different approaches taken and each of these has provided
>   unique insight into various aspects of interplanetary travel.  I
>   wanted to see if there are other perspectives that I haven't seen that
>   might prove to be equally valuable.

How would I ask such a question without getting it closed or am I stuck doing my own research?

It might be impossible to select a "best" answer but that doesn't mean there couldn't be many very good ones.

Comment: I like the idea...maybe narrow it to *effective techniques for 3D mapping?*  You could also make it a series of questions that answer that overall question by the end of the series.

Comment: Your question is not so bad, we have other questions similar to yours already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're that far off, actually.  You have a problem (mapping a solar system) and you want to know how to do it (just what SE is for).  What's missing are criteria for success.

Instead of asking "what tools/techniques are there", which is pretty general and (as you said) subjective, try to be more specific.  What tools do you already know about and in what ways did they fail you?  What specific features are important to you?  What level of precision are you after?  (A map to include in the front of your book is different from a high-end model used in an RPG.)

In other words, instead of *starting a discussion*, try to *describe a problem*.  I'm confident that our industrious community can help you with this if you can just be a bit more specific.

Thanks for bringing your question here.