# How do I ask questions about open-ended topics? Specifically, 'big-picture' questions

Tags: discussion

I've had a few frustrating experiences with this. I have read a few posts, like [this one](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/how-do-i-create-open-ended-questions-with-subjective-answers/). And I totally agree, we should be asking questions that "*describe a problem*", more than "*start a discussion*".

Triggering question [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/30330/world-building-for-my-pen-and-paper-rpg-suggestions-on-my-random-generator) with the very helpful people talking to me.

But for many of my questions, if only because that's how I think, it's difficult to even narrow down to successful criteria for an answer. Because, and I'll try to explain this so it makes sense... the question I'm asking is based on *gestaldt*, or overall 'wholeness' or 'what-everything-means-together' of what ends up being a pretty long list of things. Like, my question isn't about any *one* of those things, it's about *the list itself*.

And if I tried to break it down any further than I have, I'd lose the actual question I had in the first place. Not to mention, if I knew whether any of my specific 'list items' was wrong, then I would've asked about it specifically.
And what if I'm just looking for general feedback, or suggestions, or just plain validation? "Is this general thing good? What would you change?" kind of thing. I do know what I want out of it, but I don't know what the specific problem is.

I feel like all of those things are still valuable here, if understandably hard to answer. I want to improve on this, while *also getting activity and helpful feedback on the questions I actually have*. But I apparently lack some technique there.

Help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, your asking about building a system, which is a complex topic in my opinion. I'm sure it would be easier to provide an answer if you limited yourself to one or some specific aspects only.

However, the main problem has already been summarized by Frostfyre:

> I believe the issue here is that a "What do you think?" question is
>   inherently hard/impossible to determine a "best" answer. Open-ended
>   questions are accepted if they have criteria for determining the best
>   answer, but I don't see how you could define criteria here without
>   having solved your issue in the first place

That was pretty clear in the vocabulary of the question:

- Suggestions on my random generator
- Gives me validation?
- How can I improve this?
- I’d like to get a bit of feedback
- What do you think?

For the moment, your post is asking for a discussion or a brainstorming. This doesn't suit the Q/A format of Stack Exchange well. It would be much easier and efficient to have a discussion on chat or on a forum.

**Why are/should opinion-based questions closed on Stack Exchange?**: My personal explanation

It's just a matter of opinions and ideas.  Opinions can't be wrong since they are not based on facts, knowledge or anything meaningful. Everyone can have a different opinion and since opinions can't be wrong, all the answers are good. But if answers can't be wrong: how useful is the question? (For you and the other users).

Furthermore, determining what is good and if there is something missing is rather subjective.

Examples of recently closed (last 4 months) opinion-based questions:

- [What sort of government might very long-lived humans form with normal humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/what-sort-of-government-might-very-long-lived-humans-form-with-normal-humans)
- [The initial reaction of the society about a new human race](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23027/the-initial-reaction-of-the-society-about-a-new-human-race)
- [What can you disguise a space ship as?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/what-can-you-disguise-a-space-ship-as)
- [We burst their bubble. Now what?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/22702/we-burst-their-bubble-now-what)
- [What emotions should my wizard keep?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/what-emotions-should-my-wizard-keeps)
- [How differently would the societies have evolved if every person is allowed to commit one murder?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25061/how-differently-would-the-societies-have-evolved-if-every-person-is-allowed-to-c)

Answer (score 6):

On the top of [Vincent's answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2786/9685), I would like to point out two ways to get some feed back on your question, which does not involve any vote to close and too specific rules.

- [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions).
- [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat).

There are often some people on chat willing to discuss a possible question. Note that you can also ask question there about people's opinion. I know I had some braimstorming problem for a story, and I could discussed it on the chat, when it would have been closed on main.